# How to export a file with Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, export

There are many similar questions out there, I know, however my case is slightly different and I have tried the approaches describes in those answers but still didn't work. I know, I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what.

I have this structure:

root
   -- models
      -- categories.js
      -- ...
   -- routes
      -- main.js
      -- ...
app.js
...

So in my categories I have the following functions/structure:

```
/*
 * Initial variable setting
 */
var Db              = require('mongodb').Db,
    Connection      = require('mongodb').Connection,
    Server          = require('mongodb').Server,
    BSON            = require('mongodb').BSON,
    ObjectID        = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

Categories = function(host, port) {

    this.db = new Db('hoiepos', new Server(host, port, { safe: false }, { auto_reconnect: true }, {}));

    this.db.open(function(){});

};

/*
 * Get collection
 */
Categories.prototype.getCollection = function(callback) {

    this.db.collection('categories', function(error, category_collection) {

        if(error) callback(error);

        else callback(null, category_collection);

    });

};
...
exports.Categories = Categories;
```

There are obviously other functions within the file, but for brevity sake I've omitted them. In my routes file I've got:

```
var Categories = require('./models/categories');

exports.Melo = function(req, res) {

    Categories.findAll(function(error, prds) {

        res.send(prds);

    });

};
```

And in my app.js I have:

```
var route = require('./routes').Melo;

app.get('/test', route);
```

Yet when I try start Node I get an error saying that Node can't find the module './models/categories'.

Its important to notice that in models/ and in routes/ there will other files i.e.: /models/users, /models/orders, routes/users, routes/orders, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Please note I'm not using Mongoose.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If Node can't find the module './models/categories', you probably just using wrong path. If your project structure like this:

root

--models

----categories.js

--routes

----index.js

, then in route file you should use `var Categories = require('../models/categories');`

Comment: Yes, but in that case, the error I get is a different one: Object #<Object> has no method 'findAll' which even though I haven't added in the example above is present in the categories.js file.

Comment: Change last line in categories (`exports.Categories = Categories;`) on `module.exports = new Categories();`, and it will work. You errors is: 1) you passing to constructor function instead of object to export 2) you passing it as property of exports object, not as object itself.

Comment: Hi Berrunder. Unfortunately that didn't work either. Now I got an error from MongoDB module: /.../node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:15
    throw new Error("host must be specified [" + host + "]");
          ^
Error: host must be specified [undefined]
    at new exports.ConnectionPool (/.../node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:15:11)

Comment: Well, obviously it is because nothing passed in categories constructor. You should change `module.exports = new Categories();` on `module.exports = new Categories(host, port);`; host and port must be defined and assigned before this line, of course. Or you can change this line on `module.exports = Categories;` and use it in routes like this: `var Categories = require('../models/categories'); var category = new Categories(host, port);`, and then `category.findAll(function(error, prds) {
        res.send(prds);
    });`

Comment: Actually, your already exported file in Node.js, so question is answered, and now you having troubles with mongodb. I don't know why you using Db object in such way, but you doing it wrong in many ways: for example, empty callback in `db.open` is pointless, actually you should do all work with database in this callback - otherwise, you can't guarantee what database isn't closed while you operating with it. Maybe you should read documentation and examples more carefully: [Db() documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html).